# Numpy array - reshape and slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I get an IndexError while trying to slice my data. The data is an object array of word tokens and shape (10848135,) stored as a text file. Before reshaping the array to 2D, I need advise with the below:

1. how am I able to review my data (or file) using numpy to ensure the array isn't an array of lists   or arrays with varying size - it's a daunting task to manually review the data file - ?
2. how am I able to convert dtype object array to integer, as function to_categorical requires int dtype ?
3. what considerations should I take note of while slicing my array ?

Below is the function that throws the index error:

```
def encode_words(self, dataset):
    data = dataset.split('\n')
    newShape = 2, -1
    tokenizer = Tokenizer()
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data)
    sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data)
    vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
    sequences = array(sequences)
    #sequences = np.array2string(sequences)
    sequences  = np.reshape(sequences, newShape)
    #sequences = np.array2string(sequences)
    print(sequences.dtype)
    print(sequences.shape)
    X, y = sequences[:-1], sequences[-1]
    print(y.dtype)
    #y = np.array2string(y)
    y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)
    seq_length = X.shape[1]
    return X, y, vocab_size, seq_length, tokenizer
```

Below is the error message:

```
Reloaded modules: WordEmbedding

object
(2, 104309)
object
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-18-9db02c6b1f06>", line 1, in <module>
  runfile('/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project/processor.py', wdir='/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project')

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/envs/researchProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
  execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/envs/researchProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
  exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project/processor.py", line 15, in <module>
  X,y,vocab_size,seq_length,tokenizer = emb.encode_words(seq_data)

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/deep_learning_project/WordEmbedding.py", line 77, in encode_words
  y = to_categorical(y, num_classes=vocab_size)

File "/home/asifa/anaconda3/envs/researchProject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/np_utils.py", line 25, in to_categorical
  y = np.array(y, dtype='int')

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: what line is it failing on? 1.Check the shape and dtypes of the object, 2. which framework are you calling `to_categorical`

Comment: It's failing on  X, y = sequences[:,:-1], sequences[:,-1] due to the array being 1D. The dtype is object. Before calling reshape function, I'll like to examine the structure of the array to ensure it's not an array of lists or arrays.

Comment: I'm using keras.utils to call to_categorical.

Comment: if 1D slice without row input, `X, y = sequence[:-1], sequence[-1]`

Comment: Thanks @ksooklall, but the error still persists. I'll appreciate any further suggestions.

Comment: can you post the exact error

Comment: I have updated the code and below it, is the error message